# Nested loops in xsl-fo

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

```
    <years>
        <year yearValue="2012">
            <months>
                <month monthValue="4">
                    <projectElements>
                        <projectElement projectElementValue="756" />
                    </projectElements>
                </month>
                <month monthValue="8">
                    <projectElements>
                        <projectElement projectElementValue="12345" />
                    </projectElements>
                </month>
            </months>
        </year>
        <year yearValue="2013">
            <months>
                <month monthValue="8">
                    <projectElements>
                        <projectElement projectElementValue="ffff" />
                        <projectElement projectElementValue="12345" />
                    </projectElements>
                </month>
            </months>
        </year>
    </years>
```

I have an xml file as seen above. In my .fo file I want a loop like this:

for every year in years, 
for every month in months
for every projectElement in projectElements

year = yearValue
month = monthValue
projectElement = projectElementValue

This does not work:

```
<xsl:for-each select="activityExport/years/year">
<xsl:for-each select="activityExport/years/year/months/month">
```

I get zero results.

This returns 4 loops as expected, but then I loose the month and year info:

```
<xsl:for-each select="activityExport/years/year/months/month/projectElements/projectElement">
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second `<xsl:for-each>` has a relative XPath expression that is attempting to address `activityExport` elements that are children of the current `year` (which do not exist, so they produce nothing).

If you correct the XPath to look relative to the context node, which is the `year` element, you will get the expected number of iterations.

Then you can solve the second issue of how to access the `year` and `month` values from inside the inner-most `<xsl:for-each>`. Below are two examples of how you can do that:

1.) In order to use the nested `<xsl:for-each>` and be able to retain a reference to context of the context node from the outer `<xsl:for-each>` you can set a variable and reference the variable from inside the nested `<xsl:for-each>` statements:

```
<xsl:for-each select="years/year">
  <xsl:variable name="yearValue" select="@yearValue"/>
  <xsl:for-each select="months/month">
    <xsl:variable name="monthValue" select="@monthValue"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="projectElements/projectElement">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat('year = ', $yearValue, 
                                   ' month = ', $monthValue, 
                                   ' projectElement = ', @projectElementValue, 
                                   '&#xA;')"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

2.) Avoid the use of variables and address the ancestor nodes from the context node of the inner-most `<xsl:for-each>`:

```
<xsl:for-each select="years/year">
  <xsl:for-each select="months/month">
     <xsl:for-each select="projectElements/projectElement">
         <xsl:value-of select="concat('year = ', ancestor::year/@yearValue, 
                                      ' month = ', ancestor::month/@monthValue, 
                                      ' projectlement = ', @projectElementValue, 
                                      '&#xA;')"/>
     </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

3.) Use a single `<xsl:for-each>`

```
<xsl:for-each select="years/year/
                       months/month/
                        projectElements/projectElement">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('year = ', ancestor::year/@yearValue, 
                                 ' month = ', ancestor::month/@monthValue, 
                                 ' projectlement = ', @projectElementValue, 
                                 '&#xA;')"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

---

You could also eliminate `<xsl:for-each>` and use `<xsl:apply-templates>`:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="years/year/months/month/projectElements/projectElement"/>
```

with a template defined

```
<xsl:template match="projectElement">
   <xsl:value-of select="concat('year = ', ancestor::year/@yearValue, 
                                ' month = ', ancestor::month/@monthValue, 
                                ' projectElement = ', @projectElementValue, 
                                '&#xA;')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Each of the examples produces the following output from the sample XML:

```
year = 2012 month = 4 projectElement = 756
year = 2012 month = 8 projectElement = 12345
year = 2013 month = 8 projectElement = ffff
year = 2013 month = 8 projectElement = 12345
```

Answer (score 1):

The context of the outside loop yields "activityExport/years/year" so the inside loop should be relative to this path (or months/month).

Comment: It seems that you only need to follow the suggestion here and you'd be set.  Its a matter of "context" and the context of your inner loop carries on from the context of your outer loop (as @Kevin Brown suggested)